Authentication issue against proxy when using maven behind a corporate proxy
Good morning, I am currently using maven behind a corporate proxy and I am having problems when managing external dependencies. The issue here is that I have already configured my setting.xml file in the .m2 folder, however, from what I can see, it seems that among the parameters that maven sends to download the packages, the username and password are not sent:
This is how I have my setting.xml file configured in the .m2 folder:

This is how I see the command being executed when trying to install packages from IntellijIdea:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\E10697\Desktop\Trabajo-New\AMBIENTES\DEV\GITLAB\Microservicios\ms-bss-userprofile -Djansi.passthrough=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.162.64.36 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.162.64.36 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dmaven.home=C:\Users\E10697\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\1iopthnavndlasol9gbrbg6bf2\apache-maven-3.6.3 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Users\E10697\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\1iopthnavndlasol9gbrbg6bf2\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\m2.conf "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=58688:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\E10697\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\1iopthnavndlasol9gbrbg6bf2\apache-maven-3.6.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\E10697\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\1iopthnavndlasol9gbrbg6bf2\apache-maven-3.6.3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2024.1.4 -DskipTests=true install
I don't see that the username and password are being passed at any time. The error I get is the following:
*[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project user-profile: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.tmve.customer:user-profile:jar:1.0.34-DEV: Failed to collect dependencies at tmve:encryption-library:jar:1.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for tmve:encryption-library:jar:1.0.0: Could not transfer artifact tmve:encryption-library:pom:1.0.0 from/to nexus-repo-np (http://10.164.5.37:8081/repository/maven-releases/): proxy authentication failed for http://10.164.5.37:8081/repository/maven-releases/tmve/encryption-library/1.0.0/encryption-library-1.0.0.pom, status: 407 Proxy Authentication Required -> [Help 1]*

When running the mvn verify command this is the output:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project user-profile: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.tmve.customer:user-profile:jar:1.0.34-DEV: Failed to collect dependencies at tmve:encryption-library:j
ar:1.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for tmve:encryption-library:jar:1.0.0: Could not transfer artifact tmve:encryption-library:pom:1.0.0 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [nexus-repo-np (http://10.164.5.37:8081/repository/maven-releases/, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]

What configuration could I be missing?

First you are using an older IntelliJ version... also your configuration shows you are using an old Maven version (3.6.3)...better upgrade to most recent version... furthermore I strongly recommend to test the setup on plain command line... Just try mvn verify on plain command line also no from the terminal called from your IDE...

@khmarbaise I just updated my question with the output of the mvn verify command

@khmarbaise My Intellij idea is updated, only the folder is shown with the initial version that I installed

Please check this: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html#how-to-fix-when-i-get-a-http-repository-blocked

@khmarbaise I have already solved the issue of the blocked repository, however, I still have the problem with the proxy authentication.

Could you please share screenshots of your Maven Settings (Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven) and it's "Importing" and "Runner" sub-pages? Does Maven work as intended when you run it from the OS Command Prompt?
